# Floating Point Homomorphic Encryption Schemes

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Are there any homomorphic schemes that can homomorphically compute addition and/or multiplication of encrypted floating Point data?

Comment: As you should be able to emulate FP using integer based instructions I presume that any homomorphic scheme that has the right operations available can also be used for FP calculations. If that will be efficient is unlikely. FP ops are lossy most of the time and therefore not very usable for reversible encryption; encryption schemes that are natively based on FP are rather uncommon.

Comment: I cant get your point .... what I read is that a chance of the FP data cannot be under the cloud computations........
And can you please explain more why FP ineffective